# Debug a Java application remotely on Yarn without a deterministic port

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, jdwp

I have already googled and known to use the following options to enable debug a remote Java application.

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

However, my application will run in Yarn, and there may be several processes in one machine. So I cannot set a deterministic port in the java options due to the port conflicts. The pain of Yarn is that Yarn does not manage the port resources, so I don't know unused ports.

We have similar requirement for JMX. Fortunately, we can start JMX server in our application by ourselves, such as

```
  def start(port: Int): Int = {
    if (jmxConnectorServer != null) {
      // TODO log or throw error?
    }
    try {
      LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
    }
    catch {
      case e: java.rmi.server.ExportException if e.getCause != null && e.getCause.isInstanceOf[java.net.BindException] => {
        // TODO
        println(s"port $port already in use, try ${port + 1}")
        return start(port + 1)
      }
    }

    val env = new JHashMap[String, Any]()
    env.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate", "false")
    env.put("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", "false")

    val url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:" + port + "/jmxrmi")
    val mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()
    jmxConnectorServer = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, env, mBeanServer)
    jmxConnectorServer.start()

    port
  }
```

In the `start` method, we will try ports until we find an available one then return this port.

So I'm looking for similar APIs in JDWP. Thanks for your help in advance.